# How to use Fiddler to check response codes of multiple URLs ?

Tags: fiddler

Please suggest how to use the composer. Is there a way I can just input a file with a list of URLs and have fiddler check those links for me ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in feature that performs exactly that function, but you can easily write script that does this. Use the `utilIssueRequest` method on the Proxy object to send a request to a target URL. See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp for a full script example.